# Why do you not need sun protection whe the UV index is 3?

Tags: chemical-biology

In Australia, they recommend sun protection when the UV index is above 3.
Why is this? Surely whenever it's above 0 there are still UV rays hitting your skin?
Would 10 minutes in the sun with a UV index of 6 be the same as 20 minutes in the sun with a UV index of 3? If so, surely 10 minutes in a UV 6 index would be bad, and therefore 20 minutes in UV index 3 would also be bad?

Comment: The scale is linear, but I would bet it doesn't linearly correlate to sun burn due to other factors that aren't included like your body's natural rate of healing. I would imagine below a certain threshold, the UV index is low enough where the rate of damage is less than the rate of repair or at least the difference between the two is very small.

Comment: Something like you do not need gloves to handle a body at 40 degree Celsius :)

Comment: All depends -- an albino would use it all the time, darker-skinned people might not need as much.